# UIKit messages deallocated object during segue on iOS 6

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

After upgrading xcode and compiling my app using iOS 6 SDK I got many crashes among the app. From what I was able to track down it looks like UIKit messages deallocated view controller during modal segue instead of the newly created one. Here's how it looks:

I have a Tabbar Controller which displays a Navigation Controller. Another view controller that is being presented by the Navigation Controller displays a Modal View Controller.

TabbarController --> NavigationController --> ViewController (presenting) --
                                                              | shows using modal segue |
                                                              --> ViewController (presented)

Steps to cause the crash:

1. Access the View Controller (presenting) in hierarchy shown above. It is not root view cntrl but higher.
2. Trigger the segue to the modal view controller.
3. Pick a tab from the tab bar (whichever) and go back to the same View Controller (presenting). Picking a tab calls popToRoot on the Navigation Controller.
4. Again trigger the modal segue to the View Controller (presented)
5. Crash: Zombie object - View Controller (presented) - got messaged

Why?
It looks like on previous iOS when popToRoot was called and View Controller (presenting) was being cleaned up also the modal view was destroyed. So when it was accessed again it was recreated and presented.
On iOS 6 from what Allocations Instrumentation shows the modal view is destroyed together with 
View Controller (presenting). But when it's being accessed for some reason UIKit creates a new modav view controller but then messages the old one that is not existent anymore. Doesn't make sense.

One other thing that makes me wonder is that on iOS 5 Allocations Instrumentation tool never shows me the View Controller (presented) with retain count = 0 but iOS 6 does (afterwards it makes it -1).

I know this is probably very difficult question to help me with but maybe someone was already tackling problems with iOS 6 and such segues?

From Allocations Instrumentation tool I can tell that many things got changed in the implementation of segues on iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

I've end up implementing custom segues for presenting those modal views. Seems like a quite good idea here.
Maybe one is not supposed to display a modal view inside tab bar view?